# Does anybody have suggestions for a really stable TCP Client in Android?

Tags: android, tcp, client-server

I'm developing an application that uses an Android tablet as the user interface to a custom Linux box.  The two devices are connected by TCP (the Android is the Client, the box is the Server).  There is only every 1 client per server.  Also, I used this example to build my TCP Client code:

http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Java:Tutorials:Simple_TCP_Networking

I use the same writers and readers, but a different method for initializing the connection (an AsyncTask).

My TCP interactions between the Android and the remote system are ALWAYS:

```
  1) The Android sends a command to do something.
  2) The Server does it and sends a reply.
```

I've been treating the case where the TCP socket times out (in 5 seconds) and throws an IOException, as a loss of link, whereupon my software goes about the process of re-establishing communications with the Server.  (5 seconds is way longer than necessary to complete any existing system command, BTW)

There are couple of problems:

```
  1) Establishing (and Re-establishing) WIFI communications to my server takes
     a significant amount of time.  It's not a big deal at start up, but running
     through it again definitely doesn't sit well with the users.

  2) I've seen PLENTY of examples where the command was sent, the server executed
     it, and sent a reply, but for some reason, the reply just doesn't show up in
     my StreamReader.
```

As far as I can tell, nothing is wrong with the Server or the link, but my Android just didn't receive the response -- and I have verified that my Server is definitely sending it.

Can anybody recommend some idea for a more "bulletproof" TCP connection concept??  Perhaps I might ignore a small number of these errors (assuming there's a way to clean up after them...  Is there?)  Perhaps there are more reliable ways to write to and read from the socket??

Any suggestions will be gratefully accepted and acted upon.  Thanks,
R.

Comment: Why are you loosing the connection? Wifi loosing connection or you dropping the connection after sending? You could use e.g. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to check the traffic.

Comment: Are you using a [WiFiLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html) and other locks to keep the device (& radio) from sleeping?

Comment: Zapl, I'm not losing the connection, that's the problem.  While it certainly is possible to lose any part of the connection at any time -- wifi, server, what have you (It's all mobile and running on batteries) -- as far as I can tell, everything is running normally.  Except that the response the server sent me never shows up in my InputStream.  I'm just trying to find a rational way to respond to this.

Comment: Jens, I don't think so, but I'll look into it.  I am using a WakeLock, but I assume that's not the same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the answer seems to be what Jens suggested.  Nicely done, sir (I assume)...
There's a setting for WiFi sleep you can access in the Android settings menu -- but it's apparently not helpful.

On the other hand, acquiring a WiFi lock (use WifiManager.createWifiLock ("Tag"); to get one) seems to have done the trick nicely.

Before anyone asks, though, I've got no information at all on the behavior of locked or unlocked Wifi.  I can't tell you anything about what might convince your WiFi to work or not in your application.  All can say is get the lock, and screw the battery...

R.